# About PHP and the xHTML5 content-type

Tags: php, xml, xhtml, content-type, xhtml-1.0-strict

So as I read at the W3C  I could add a XML directive at the beggining of my file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

But my file needs to be dynamic and that's why I used the .php extension. Sure I can `echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';` before the DOCTYPE but the content-type remains `text/html` and if I change it in my PHP headers to `application/xhtml+xml, cahrset=UTF-8` I am prompted for download. I know I could just use the `text/html` content-type but I want to have at least valid xHTML (and CSS). I've always been following the standards and I got used to it. I won't start writing invalid HTML/xHTML.

EDIT:

Here's the code:

```
    header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8');
```

EDIT 2:

```
<!-- ... -->
<noscript>
    <link href="./no-java-script.css.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/no-javascript.aspx" />
</noscript>
<!-- ... -->
<noscript>
    <div onload="return false;" class="no-script"><p>Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript! Click <a href="/no-javascript.aspx" hreflang="en-US" class="show">here</a> if it doesn't redirect you automatically.</p></div>
</noscript>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: How do you set the header to `application/xhtml+xml`? Can you add the code to the question?

Comment: Which browser you are using? You don't want to tell, you are still using IE <= 6 (=> XP)?

Comment: Win7 SP1, tested in FF 31.0, IE 11 and Chrome 36.

Comment: All 3 Browsers work for me with your code :/

Comment: Ooops, looks like I had a typo and that's why it didn't recognize the code... Anyway I'd really like to use the `<noscript>` tag... but well - back to `text/html`, the xml declaration is optional and it won't do so much, but the `noscript` tag can save me from users with disabled JavaScript, so I'd rather choose `noscript`... *sniff sniff* how hard was it to make such a decision... I'd like to have both but the spec is broken and I have to follow it. Maybe in the future it'll be finally fixed.

Comment: I know what you mean bro, I hate it when it comes to such hard decisions...

Comment: @PowerUser What are you trying to do with the `<noscript>`? It might be valid HTML5, but it's still discouraged. Can you give an example of how you use it? I'm pretty sure I can come up with a `<noscript>`-less alternate that still works fine with Javascript disabled.

Comment: @PowerUser For the div that should be visible when Javascript is disabled, that's easy. Just make a visible div and then use Javascript to hide it (or remove it from the DOM tree). Ditto for the CSS. You have me at the meta refresh though: there doesn't seem to be a way to include a meta refresh element and then to cancel the pending reload with Javascript. Sorry.

Comment: Could I have a code example as an answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this document:

http://www.webstandards.org/learn/articles/askw3c/sep2003/

> But some browsers don’t know about application/xhtml+xml.
>
> Indeed, and that’s one of the biggest current issues with the adoption
>   of the new MIME type, especially since Internet Explorer doesn’t
>   recognize it (at least for any version up to 6.x on both Windows and
>   Mac OS). Of course, this is a common problem with adoption of new
>   technologies and it usually improves over time.

So yes, we should use `application/xhtml+xml` in a few years. Currently it is a bad idea, because not all common used browser support it.

So my advise: Use for the next 5 years `text/html`. The good thing is, Xp support ended. Sometime maybe come the day, the last IE 6 version is elimated ;)

Comment: "...the last IE 6 version is eliminated..."
What wise words, no seriously I'd really like to finally drop those annoying conditional IE comments... And what you said about the future: I'd really like to belive/see it...

Comment: @PowerUser go to china, and ask them to change quick :D https://www.modern.ie/en-us/ie6countdown

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you must `echo` the XML declaration line in PHP when the php.ini value of `short_open_tag` is `on` or `1` (which is the default, and quite common). So, everything ok with this one.

As for the header: The `application/xhtml+xml` MIME type may be the correct one, but (as you experienced), some browsers are not set up to handle this type themselves, so they offer to download it. There are plenty of discussions of how to handle this, see for example http://www.webstandards.org/learn/articles/askw3c/sep2003/ or enter "xhtml mime type" into your favourite search engine.